# converting a csv file headers and values into a list

Tags: c#

I have this unique requirement, where I will have a CSV file with headers and only one row of values. All values will be of string type. I need to read the csv and put the headers in one List object and values in another list object. How do I do it? the columns are not defined, there can be 5 columns , 10 columns, any number but there will always be one row. Any sample code to achieve this in c#?

Input csv file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val1,val2,val3,val4
```

Output:

```
ListA : {col1,col2,col3,col4}
ListB : {val1,val2,val3,val4}
```

Comment: Well, a simple idea could be `var lists =  File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(row=>row.Split(',').ToList())` and then you have ListA=lists[0] and ListB=lists[1]

Comment: For simple files you can simply read all lines and split them. For files that may contain quoted fields, separators inside fields etc you can use one of the many CSV parsing libraries like CsvHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with linq, you could use:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("path of your file").Select(line => line.Split(',').ToList())
```

so result[0] is the first list (cols), and result[1] is the second list (values)

Comment: mm, i have the content of the file as a stream

Comment: thts right, i m just thinking implementing the stream source in your code.

Comment: the result is in string?